# Did I install from USB correctly? (Blank screen when USB drive removed)

Tags: usb, system-installation

I created a USB of 12.04 LTS using the procedure at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows (starting from a Windows XP system).  After trying the system a few times, (no issues except performance), I rebooted and selected Install, replacing the current system.  At the end of the install, I was instructed to reboot.  Since the USB drive was still plugged in, I was surprised not to see an instruction to remove it, so as not to just boot from that drive again.  There was no such instruction, so I just pulled out the drive.  The screen went blank and the system was totally unresponsive.

I forced power down and then back up.  Ubuntu (now from the hard drive) came up and seems OK, except for an issue with saving settings (which I will document separately).

Was this the correct procedure and is the blank screen result as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you removed the USB, there was an IO error that made the system unresponsive. If you were instructed to reboot it means that the installation was completed correctly. Try in the future not to do this since it could cause problems.

Comment: So an improvement would be for the final prompt, which states that the installation is complete, to also say that you should click on the 'Reboot' button and then promptly remove the USB device.  As I suspected, a 'Reboot' with the device left in place simply boots again from the USB and presents you with the options to 'Try' Ubuntu or 'Install' it.  At that point you have to realize what happened, force power off, remove the USB drive, and power up again.

Comment: @user249003 that should be a feature request for the ubiquity package in LaunchPad.

Answer (score 0):

You are good to go. Most systems do not boot to the USB drive automatically.;-)